# Is there a Windows Message for when any pixel in the window changes?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook, window-messages

I'm trying to execute an action when a pixel changes in a window by using `SetWindowsHookEx`. I can successfully recieve Windows messages, but most messages are called while no screen updates occur, and some messages are called more than once on one pixel.

```
// WH_GETMESSAGE doesn't call the callback for some reason...
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, hhookSysMsg, hinstDLL, GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, NULL));
```

I tried listening for `WM_PAINT`, `WM_NCPAINT`, and `WM_ERASEBKGND`, but for some reason they don't fire every time - for example, in Notepad, it does not fire when the scrollbar colors change (for example when hovering over them with the cursor) or changing the text itself.

```
switch (msg->message)
    {
    // doesn't catch all screen updates!
    case WM_PAINT:
    case WM_NCPAINT:
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        // Bit-blit the screen to a file/process the screen/etc.
        ...
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Can someone help me out with this? If there's no concrete event that runs when a pixel is changed within a window, is there a list of events that I can do a switch-case expression on?

Comment: Notepad uses more than one window.  The interesting stuff happens in an EDIT control, a child of the outer frame window.  Use the Spy++ utility to see this.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I didn't know that utility existed! I attached my callback to all the child HWNDs while listening for `WM_PAINT` and `WM_COMMAND` messages and it did the job for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no message that notifies a client about the change of a pixel's color. This wouldn't really be useful either: Clients are in charge of drawing to the window's (client) area. If they need to know when a pixel changes color, it can monitor the state itself.

If you need to monitor the change of a pixel's color in a foreign process, the system won't help you with that. You'd be left with hooking all API calls that potentially change the color of a pixel, and keep state information around to determine a change in state.

Comment: Alright, while I haven't found an event that would monitor for these changes, I found something close: a combination of `WM_PAINT` and `WM_COMMAND` - it did the job pretty well, informing my code when the screen has been updated.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Painting is at the discretion of any given application. While common, performing all rendering in response to a `WM_PAINT` message is not contractual. Notably, applications that don't use the GDI for rendering are likely to employ different schemes.